# onchange hijacks onclick

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

Modifying the text and then clicking on the button triggers only the `onchange` code

But I need to know whether the button has been clicked:

```
<input type="text" onchange="alert('change')" value="Text">
<input type="button" onclick="alert('click')" value="Button">
```

What do I need to change to get the click handler?

Comment: Not clear to me what's not working. Please take a look the following jsfiddle sample and let me know if this that's what you would expect http://jsfiddle.net/7JZFE/

Answer (score 2):

That works fine, it's `alert()` that sucks.

I don't know the exact details around it, but I've noticed in the past that `alert()` can mess with DOM events in strange ways when those events would occur together.

```
<input type="text" onchange="console.log('change')" value="Text">
<input type="button" onclick="console.log('click')" value="Button">​
```

See here: http://jsfiddle.net/25EsQ/
(Make sure to bring up the JS console so you can see the output)

The good news is this is a debugging issue only (hopefully) and when you use real and useful JS code instead, it should work as you expect.

Answer (score 0):

The alert comes up between the onmousedown and the onmouseup events, causing an onclick to never trigger